# Protractor: browser.wait isn't working after an element.click()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using protractor to test [this project](https://github.com/christo8989/angular-busy) which can be seen [here](https://github.com/christo8989/angular-busy/tree/master/demo).

Here's the test:

- Set the Delay to 2000ms.
- Set the Duration to 4000ms.
- Click the Demo button.
- Time and Wait for the loading indicator (spinner).
- Write the time waited (or the assertion for the real test).

However, `browser.wait` doesn't seem to be returning.

**Code**: What I think should work...

```
//Inside it("test", function() {
set(delayInput, 2000); //custom sauce but it sets the element
set(durationInput, 4000); //custom sauce but it sets the element
var tStart = 0;
var spinner = element(by.css('.cg-busy.cg-busy-animation.ng-scope'));
var waitForMe = function() {
    return spinner.getAttribute('class')
        .then(data => data.includes('ng-hide') === false);
}
demoButton.click()
    .then(() => tStart = Date.now());
browser.wait(waitForMe, 4000)
    .then(() => console.log(Date.now() - tStart));
```

**Code**: Maybe something else that should work... (small difference)

```
demoButton.click()
    .then(() => tStart = Date.now());
    .then(() => 
        browser.wait(waitForMe, 4000)
            .then(() => console.log(Date.now() - tStart))
    );
```

**Code**: Locators and Custom Sauce

```
//btw, I can see the test correctly execute so I am actually getting the elements.
var delayInput = element(by.model('delay')),
    durationInput = element(by.model('minDuration')),
    demoButton = element(by.css('.btn')),
    spinner = element(by.css('.cg-busy.cg-busy-animation.ng-scope')),
    set = function(elem, data) {
        elem.clear();
        elem.sendKeys(data);
    };
```

I keep getting `Failed: Wait timed out after 4056ms` which could mean the `spinner` always includes `'ng-hide'`. But, if I inspect the webpage and run the test manually, 'ng-hide' goes away (which makes sense). SO, I'm thinking it has to do with the promises or some blocking function but I'm just not sure.

**EDIT**

**Code**: I've also tried...

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(spinner), 4000)
    .then(() => console.log(Date.now() - tStart));
```

I tried extending the Duration and timeout to 15000ms. This game me the following error:

```
Failed: Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, .cg-busy.cg-busy-animation.ng-scope). 
    The following tasks were pending:
     - $timeout: function (){
                        tracker.durationPromise = null;
                    }
```

Comment: The browser.wait is definitely working, that's why you get the timeout error after 4 seconds because you set it to 4 seconds.  That means your `waitForMe` function is taking longer than that.  What if you make the timeout longer?

Comment: Oh, I think you are missing a `return` statement.  `return data.includes('ng-hide') === false)`

Comment: @Gunderson I thought the lambda expression was syntactic sugar and returns the value. Plus, I tried it out and it still gives me a timeout. I set the timeout to 4 seconds because the spinner's duration is 4 seconds. This would mean that `waitForMe` takes at least 2 seconds to complete? Is that what you think?

Comment: Ahh yep sorry that syntax does return.  But if the spinners duration is 4 seconds then your `browser.wait` needs to be longer than that.  Try making it 10 or 20 seconds just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Gunderson Part of the point is that it shouldn't be timing out. If it's timing out then how do I test this situation?

Comment: Well, did you try it?  Better to know that's not it than to think that's not it.  And `browser.wait` is useful for things when you don't know how long it will take, it executes ASAP when it finds what it's waiting for (or times out if not).  Could be .001 seconds, could be 5 seconds.  It's not a guaranteed wait for 10 or 20 seconds unless your app is taking that long.

Comment: What's your reasoning for thinking that it shouldn't be timing out?  Don't see why you wouldn't verify that by extending the timeout for debugging purposes...

Comment: @Gunderson This code, `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);`, from their website makes me think it can handle what I'm trying to do. You're right though, I'll check it out and see.

Comment: @Gunderson See the new edit.